# I see deleted posts!

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I just found out that I can see all my deleted answers on my profile page here on Meta.

Excited about the change, I visited [another user's profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157251). I can see his deleted questions and answers as well:

[image: screenshot]

Is this a new feature or is it a bug? (Please let it be a feature.)

Comment: Is this only on meta right now? I can't see any of my deleted answers on SO.

Comment: Seems to be Meta only. I can't see anything on SO or SU.

Comment: +1 for the example account you picked to link :p

Comment: Maybe this affect 10k+ users only?

Comment: It's a bug. Enjoy it while it lasts ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Well, I had to pick an account with deleted posts. It was the first that came to my mind...

Comment: I can't see what you're seeing in your screenshot at that link you posted.

Comment: @Yannis You seem sure of this. Did someone in the TL confirm this as a bug?

Comment: @juergend: That would make sense for others' deleted posts.

Comment: Quick! Let's find **all** the deleted posts while we still can!

Comment: @animuson See if `isdeleted:1` works in the search.

Comment: All I have to say is: $@*&^!

Comment: [looking straight to your eyes] : `I see DEAD Posts!`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The user pages have different visibility on deleted content than most other places - I misused an existing property for checking a user's ability to see deleted content and this was the result.

It should be fixed now.

Comment: You call that fixed? Meh.

Comment: __Please unfix it, pretty please.__

Comment: *Once again shrouded in mystery* :)

Comment: You, sir, are a tease!